# My video is not playing in both Brave browser nor Firefox

Tags: html, html5-video

I am new to HTML and CSS (So that may be the issue). I entered the following code into my html doc:

```
<video controls width="700">   
     <source src="video/PristineCustomCleansVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The video I want to play is inside a folder called video. The index.html and the video folder are nested inside a folder together.

The video shows up on the site I'm making as a gray rectangle with controls (in a Brave browser). When I press play nothing happens. I also tried opening my page in Firefox and within the gray rectangle it says "No video with supported format and MIME type found."

I looked up this question and have found so many confusing suggestions. Whatever you recommend, please do it as if I know very little about computers (I thought I knew a good amount until reading some of the responses and can't follow what I should do. lol)

Another issue I am considering is if I have to do a lot of work to get the video to play, will others that I send my website URL to have issues as well? This is for a class project. I have to put everything on the school's server and share the URL with the teacher.

Comment: BTW I went to my File Explorer where everything that is on my computer is stored. I right-clicked on the video, scrolled down to "Open With" and selected the Brave browser. It played in the broswer. I tried playing it with FireFox. It worked as well. It only DOESN'T work when I try playing it from within my webpage (in either browser)

Comment: Found my solution!! I'm an idiot. I had typed video/PristineCustomCleansVideo.mp4 but the folder name was "videos"!!! It was as simple as adding the "s". *face slap* Wow I feel dumb, but at least it's resolved. It took me watching someone on Youtube go through how to add a video to their site and they too had a folder called "videos" and said, "ok I should make sure to add that s at the end" Then BAM it hit me. I had named my folder videos!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If your index page and the video are located in exactly the same place you do not need the `video` folder in the path to your file. The following should work.

```
source src="PristineCustomCleansVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"
```

Comment: No the video file is inside a folder called video

Comment: OK so you do have an index page in the same location as your video folder not in the same location as your video. That does make more sense with your path. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned "The video I want to play is inside a folder called video. The index.html and the video folder are nested inside a folder together."

Comment: OK so a quick Google has thrown up lots about Firefox not playing videos and this does seem centered around MP4's.  It's due to everything from ad-blocking to out of date Firefox plugins. Might be worth a little investigation but first try Chrome or Edge etc. If your video works fine then I guess Firefox is playing games with you.

Comment: thank you. I actually messed around with the code and found my error. I'm an idiot. I had typed video/PristineCustomCleansVideo.mp4 but the folder name was "videos"!!! It was as simple as adding the "s". *face slap* felt super dumb. glad it's fixed though

Comment: Coding 101. There is always going to be a . or a / in the wrong place somewhere. Glad you worked it out :)